# Null pointer YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have problem with "YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"

I get error here :

```
`YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);`
```

Here is the full code:
**I tried to change a few things, and now I have a little more understandable error.
If I find it I will post solcuón.**

***Update Code 11/06/2015, and I get new Error :***

```
5429-5429/com.onpocket.activamutua E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onStart(Unknown Source)
```

Code :

```
public class Activity_demo extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment /*implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener */{


    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 10;
    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyBHZjt1vrkjuwCp4YqTsADNQVDf6KvAXr0";
    private String VIDEO_ID = "c_eHTMhEsHU";

    JustifiedTextView tv1;
    ConfigActiva cfg;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_own, container, false);
    TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getActivity(), "SERIF", ConfigActiva.nameFontStatic);
    ConfigActiva.languageCustom(ConfigActiva.defaultLanguageForce, getActivity());
    init(rootView);    
    return rootView;
}

    public void init(View vRoot){

    //YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
    //youTubeView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
    //YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
    //youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
            if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                String errorMessage = String.format("YouTube Error (%1$s)", errorReason.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    }
/*  @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format("YouTube Error (%1$s)",errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }*/
```

My XML

```
<fragment 
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

With this line Works, but not load video : updated 11/06/2015 22:21

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
```

Comment: You are getting a `NullPointerException` because the current view hierarchy does not contain a fragment with the id `youtubeplayerview`. In order to help you track down the problem, we need more details, starting with the complete method which contains the offending line of code. If it isn't in the `onCreate()` method where you call `setContentView()`, please include that as well. Also, you need to show us the XML file which corresponds to the id you send to `setContentView()`.

Comment: Activity_demo extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment ? So you're trying fragment inside other fragment? Bad idea, but try with getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: not work, null pointer

Comment: The `<fragment>` tag in your XML loads the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` and has absolutely nothing to do with your own `Activity_demo` class. What is the name of the XML file that this is stored in? Please also post the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` subclass, the XML file used by this `Activity`, and `activity_own.xml`. It appears that you need to learn the difference between an `Activity` and a `Fragment` and how they interact.

Comment: Note: post the **entire** XML file, including the opening `<?xml>` tag. This will ensure that you don't leave out anything important that is needed to help you fix your problem.

Comment: If remove this "tag" I get : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #122: Class is not a View com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your fragment dynamically because: [Nested fragments](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)
Just add some container with id and use this id in Transaction.replace. Also use onCreateView only for inflating and building layout. After that find for views in onViewCreated(View view, ...) from view param, it will make code cleaner.

Comment: If you need more info search for problems related to google map fragment. Same issue.

Comment: I doubt that the OP needs to worry about loading the fragment dynamically with the fragment manager. Rather they need to learn about and understand the Activity and Fragment lifecycles as well as the difference between an Activity and a Fragment. I strongly doubt that the OP needs to subclass `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`. Rather they need to move most of this code into an appropriate Activity.